# Return statement in catch block

Tags: java, return, try-catch

While coding in java i saw an odd thing happen.

while the code was written this way.

```
class lara {
    public static void main(String ...pro) {
        int o;
        try{
            o=999;
        }catch(Exception mu) {
         System.out.println("sololobo");
        }
    System.out.println(o);
}
}
```

it would show an error at the line where o is requested to be printed

"System.out.println(o);"

But when i add type a "return;" statement inside catch block like

```
class lara {
    public static void main(String ...pro) {
        int o;
        try{
            o=999;
        }catch(Exception mu){
            System.out.println("sololobo");
            return;
        }
    System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

it works perfectly.
WHY DOES THIS HAPPEN?
Is catch a function?
what function does this return statement refer to.
THANK you in advance!!

Comment: Please take the time to format your code *much* more readably, with suitable indentation and line breaks. If you're using an IDE, it will probably help you. It doesn't help that you haven't told us what the error is, either...

Comment: When you add a return statement it returns from that function in your case the `main` function, so the code after that is simple unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is happening because the `int` variable named `o` may not be initialized should an exception take place.  In your updated version with the `return`, this problem cannot happen:

```
public static void main(String ...pro) {
    int o;
    try {
        o = 999;
    } catch(Exception mu) {
        System.out.println("sololobo");
        return; // end the call to `main()` here
    }

    // now the following line can only be reached if the try
    // completes without error, which means that o will be defined
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Comment: Good explanation. Basically, the variable "o" needs to be initialized. As long as you initialize it either before the Try-Statement or even inside the Catch-Block, the code will work. Just make sure "o" is initialized. A declaration is not enough in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Without `return` you will always reach the `System.out.println(o);` statement. The compiler does not know where in the `try catch` the error occurred, it therefore does not know wether or not `o` has been correctly initialised.

*If* you return in the catch-block the `System.out.println(o);` will not be reached in case of any exception, which means if the code *is* reached, there was no exception, which in turn means that `o` has been correctly set.

Comment: yeah but still it prints whatever it has been assigned inside try block..why so..{isn't it supposed to be locally assigned ...i.e. being able to obtain it's value when it's invoked inside the try block,but not being able to obtain it when called outside the block;}

Comment: @his_dogeness there is no such thing as local assignment. It has **one** value and that is it.

Comment: aha i kinda got it ...thank you ..im new to programming,,trying to undestand it logically..i guess java is not as logical as c++

Comment: @his_dogeness c++ does not have local assignments either, get your facts straight.